# Symfony2 CSS images path gets rewritten and I get a 404

Tags: css, image, symfony, yui-compressor

I'm using Symfony2 and assetic in an existing project and I can't figure out how to refer to images in my CSS. I've put my images in: `src/Organisation/MyBundle/Resources/public/images/`

After running the assets install: `php app/console assets:install public`

I can load them in the browser correctly: `http://sitename/bundles/organisationmy/images/logo.png`

However, when I try to point to them in the CSS, with: `url('/bundles/organisationmy/images/logo.png')`

inspecting with firebug, the url gets changed in: `url('/web/bundles/organisationmy/images/logo.png')` and that results in a 404.

In my main template I have:

```
{% stylesheets filter='yui_css' output='css/output.css'
    '@MyBundle/Resources/public/css/bootstrap.min.css'
    '@MyBundle/Resources/public/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css'
    '@MyBundle/Resources/public/css/my.css'
 %}
```

And in `config.yml` I have:

```
assetic:
    debug: %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        yui_css:
            jar: %kernel.root_dir%/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar
        yui_js:
            jar: %kernel.root_dir%/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar
```

In `routing.yml` I have:

```
_assetic:
    resource: .
    type: assetic
```

I've seen this question [Symfony2 - Assetic - load images in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044631/symfony2-assetic-load-images-in-css), but I don't know if and how I can use `filter='cssrewrite'` and `filter='yui_css'` at the same time, or how to solve the problem.

Basically if I could stop Symfony2 to prefix my CSS images paths with `/web/` the problem would be solved. Or, does anyone know what is the proper way to solve this problem in Symfony2?

**UPDATE**: I've noticed that even if I put url('something.png') the CSS doesn't get updated anymore when I load the page, so I might have messed up something with command line, I've also given commands like `php app/console assetic:dump` -- how to go back to the normal dev style of modify CSS and reload page?

**UPDATE2**: I discovered that `php app/console assetic:dump --watch` updates the assets automatically as they change.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to load images in your CSS file the path must be `"bundles/(bundle name)/images/(file name)"`

**UPDATE**

make sure you have

```
write_to: %kernel.root_dir%/../web
```

under 
`assetic:` in `config.yml`

and

`background: url('/bundles/(bundle name)/images/prev.png')` in your css

then run

```
php app/console assets:install web
```

and

```
php app/console assetic:dump web
```

Comment: yes, Dave, thanks. That works perfectly from the browser, as I mentioned, I can load images from the browser. the problem is when I put URLs in CSS, as explained.

Comment: i have the same setup as you, in my CSS file i have: background: url('/bundles/mscore/img/prev.png') left 48% no-repeat; , i also have write_to:       %kernel.root_dir%/../web under assetic: in config.yml

Comment: so it should work, have you seen the **update** at the bottom of the question? I think the problem could be that my CSS loaded is not updated anymore.

Comment: make sure you have write_to: %kernel.root_dir%/../web under assetic: in config.yml and  background: url('/bundles/mscore/img/prev.png') in your css then run php app/console assets:install web then php app/console assetic:dump web

Comment: this works and is great! thanks Dave, now I can see the image also from CSS background. However, while is OK to run `php app/console assets:install web` whenever I add an image, it slow me down a lot if every time I modify CSS, I have to run `php app/console assetic:dump web` (it takes 1 minute).  it used to work on my dev machine that I modify the CSS and changes are just immediately seen, do you have an idea why is not working anymore?

Comment: You can modify css without running the commands as far as image dropping.. i don't know, never had that one

Comment: anyway, if you update your question with the suggestions in the comment (write_to:, php app/console commands), I can accept it as the answer, since it solved the problem of showing the images.