# Change password not working in FOS user bundle+ Sonata User bundle +sonata Admin Bundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, sonata-admin

I'm able to integrate FOS bundle to sonata Admin bundle using Sonata User Bundle. My login thing works fine. Now i want to add functionality like change password which is there in FOSUserBundle to sonata Admin Bundle

I can access profile functionality of FOS User Bundle using

localhost/myproject/web/app_dev.php/profile

But same thing for change password

localhost/myproject/web/app_dev.php/change-password cant access.

I want to integrate it with SonataAdminBundle as

localhost/myproject/web/app_dev.php/admin/change-password

Can you suggest me where should i change Or where i went wrong?

In my routing I have

```
fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

fos_user_profile:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
    prefix: /profile

fos_user_register:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
    prefix: /register

fos_user_resetting:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
    prefix: /resetting

fos_user_change_password:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
    prefix: /change-password
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you setup a route for the change password?

```
fos_user_change_password:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
    prefix: /profile
```

Comment: Okay...now its working it should be localhost/myproject/web/app_dev.php/profile/change-password instead of localhost/myproject/web/app_dev.php/change-password.

Comment: Now i want to add to Sonata admin bundle. I want to get css,js of sonataAdmin bundle for this. Any idea?

Comment: You could always copy change_routing.xml to your config directory and modify it as you need it. About the css / js, you can include it from sonataAdmin using assetic. Check through this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044631/symfony2-assetic-load-images-in-css