# Symfony2: trouble including images in css

Tags: php, css, symfony

I have trouble referencing images from my .css file in a symfony2 project. I have a main.css in `app/Resources/public/css` and my image directory is `app/Resources/public/images`.

I include the css sheet like so:

```
{% stylesheets '../app/Resources/public/css/*' %}
        <link href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

How would I go about referencing images in my css file?

Answer (score 0):

Use `../` to go to the previous directory (`app/Respirces/public/`), then proceed with the rest of the URL.

```
selector {
    background-image: url(../images/image.png);
}
```

Comment: That would seem like the obvious solution, but unfortunately it doesn't work. (I have no idea why). I'm actually hoping for something like assetic referencing.

Comment: This should work, are you sure the path and your rule is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Inori's answer helped me with this issue:
[Symfony2 - Assetic - load images in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044631/symfony2-assetic-load-images-in-css)

In the end I had to run assetic:dump and then referenced images like this:

```
background-image: url('/images/background.jpg');
```