# Assetic (with Symfony 2) changes the name of image files when 'assetic:dump' is run

Tags: php, symfony, assetic

Whenever I run the command `php app/console assetic:dump` all of my assets (css, javascripts, images) are successfully placed into the `web/` folder. The only issue I'm encountering is that Assetic changes the image file names, presumably for cache busting purposes, which interferes with images referenced in my css files.

When I manually place the image in `web/images/masthead-4.jpg`, it shows up correctly. I'd like to keep the cache busting on the images if possible. **I would prefer to get one of these solutions working:**

- I use the processed image in my css rule, such as

  `.is--site_landing {
   background: transparent url('../images/d755b65-aa84794_masthead-4_1-86f4322.jpg') top center no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
  }`
- Get the images to transfer from app/Resources/public/images into
  web/images without having Assetic change the name of the file?

My images are located in `%kernel.root_dir%/app/Resources/public/images`.
For instance, say I have a file `%kernel.root_dir%/app/Resources/public/images/masthead-4.jpg`.

---

#### The output of `php app/console assetic:dump` for the image file is:

```
20:22:40 [file+] /our_stuff/admin/symfony/app/../web/images/d755b65-aa84794.jpg
20:22:40 [file+] /our_stuff/admin/symfony/app/../web/images/d755b65-aa84794_masthead-4_1-86f4322.jpg
```

Now that the file is named `d755b65-aa84794_masthead-4_1-86f4322.jpg` or `d755b65-aa84794.jpg` my background-image css rule isn't finding the image.

---

#### My background CSS rule located in `%kernel.root_dir%/app/Resources/public/images`

```
    .is--site_landing {
      background: transparent url('../images/masthead-4.jpg') top center no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
    }
```

---

#### My header in my Twig layout file:

```
{% stylesheets
  'css/style.css.scss'
  filter='cssrewrite'
%}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}">
{% endstylesheets %}

{% javascripts
  'js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js'
%}
<script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}  

{%image 
  'images/masthead-4.jpg'
%}
{% endimage %}
```

**More information:**
I'm running:

- PHP 5.3.3
- Symfony 3.3
- assetic-bundle ~2.3

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044631/symfony2-assetic-load-images-in-css

Comment: Thanks for the link Andrey, I had read it in some previous Googling, but unfortunately I don't think it helps much for my case. The cssrewrite filter is working correctly and all of my images are getting placed correctly under ```web/```, and if I change the file name in my CSS to the one that Assetic generates, it works correctly.  I'd like to know why Assetic is changing my file name from ```masthead-4.jpg``` to something like ```d755b65-aa84794_masthead-4_1-86f4322.jpg``` and also how to get the CSS rule to know the new filename.

Comment: Have you tried to include `<img src="{{ asset_url }}" alt="Example" />` between `{% image %}` and `{% endimage %}` tags? Or even not using this tags at all and just use `<img>` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assetic are made for processing assets. Don't use it for the images if you don't like it to process yours images.

First, remove that, you don't need it.

```
{%image 
  'images/masthead-4.jpg'
%}
{% endimage %}
```

Next, use `php app/console assets:install --symlink` for creating the symlink in the `web` folder. Like that, your CSS file can access the image file.