# Using assetic for css relative images

Tags: php, symfony, assetic

I use asseticBundle for my files but when I use `php app/console assets:install` and `php app/console assetic:dump`, all my files are transfered except images.

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {% stylesheets filter='cssrewrite'
        '@BattutaBackBundle/Resources/public/libs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css'
        '@BattutaBackBundle/Resources/public/libs/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css'
        '@BattutaBackBundle/Resources/public/libs/iCheck/skins/flat/green.css'
        '@BattutaBackBundle/Resources/public/libs/animate/css/animate.css'
        '@BattutaBackBundle/Resources/public/libs/custom.css'
    %}

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}
```

I have images like green.png but they not transfered. that image file is important because I use it for checkbox background. How can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about resources referenced inside css files:

[Symfony2 - Assetic - load images in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044631/symfony2-assetic-load-images-in-css)

You need to use css filters which will process the css and get images required and dump them appropriately.

And you cant use @Bundle syntax for this feature.